# how to change sql query in example?

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I've tried but can not convert this t-sql to linq.

```
select title , count(number) as order_number from order
group by title
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be something like this:

```
   var result = context.order
                       .GroupBy(p=>p.title)
                       .Select(p=> new {title = p.Key, order_number = p.Count()})
```

Comment: Add column names `title = p.Key, order_number = p.Count()`.

Comment: how to group bay date title but select date and count title. ex: .GroupBy(p=>p.title).Select(p=> new {p.dateSend, order_number = p.Count()}). Get Error!

Comment: @AnaMah group by date AND title?

Comment: i want get this list -> {date, number.Count()}: {"2010", 5},{"2011" , 11},{"2012", 6}. and group by title

Comment: @AnaMah Can you write SQL query?